# Query with if and declare

Tags: sql, sql-server, declare, iif

How can a query like this be made?

```
SELECT 
PersonId, 
Name,
(
    DECLARE @p INT=(SELECT (Not1 + Not2 + Not3)/3 FROM Tablo_Not WHERE NotId=PersonId);
    DECLARE @s INT;
    IF @p>84
        SET @s=5;
    ELSE IF @p>69
        SET @s=4;
    ELSE IF @p>54
        SET @s=3;
    ELSE IF @p>44
        SET @s=2;
    ELSE
        SET @s=1;
    SELECT @s;
) AS Degree
FROM Tablo_Person;
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results. And then read up on a `case` expression.

Comment: Your syntax is all wrong. `T-SQL` is unlike other programming language that you know. You can't just use the syntax from other programming language in `T-SQL`. Please refer to the documentation for the correct syntax

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a `DECLARE` statement within a `SELECT` query like that. However, you can achieve the result by using a `CASE` expression instead of `DECLARE` and `IF` statements.

```
SELECT 
    p.PersonId, 
    p.Name,
    CASE 
        WHEN n.AverageScore > 84 THEN 5
        WHEN n.AverageScore > 69 THEN 4
        WHEN n.AverageScore > 54 THEN 3
        WHEN n.AverageScore > 44 THEN 2
        ELSE 1
    END AS Degree
FROM Tablo_Person p
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT PersonId, (Not1 + Not2 + Not3) / 3 AS AverageScore
    FROM Tablo_Not
) n ON p.PersonId = n.PersonId;
```